# Add external project to subversion repository

Tags: svn

I would like to have the following structure in my SVN Repository

```
External
   - MVC
   - MVCConttrib
   - NLog
```

I want every team member to be able to check out the External repository so nobody has to look up the SVN urls for the underlying projects, but I want the projects in the repository to be updated from their respective (external) URLs.

How can I accomplish this?

I hope my explanation is not too confusing but I don't know how else to explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you looking for [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html)?

> An externals definition is a mapping of a local directory to the URL—and ideally a particular revision—of a versioned directory [...]
>
> The convenience of the svn:externals property is that once it is set on a versioned directory, everyone who checks out a working copy with that directory also gets the benefit of the externals definition. In other words, once one person has made the effort to define the nested working copy structure, no one else has to bother—Subversion will, after checking out the original working copy, automatically also check out the external working copies.

Comment: This is great :) Actually solves another problem where I always had to distribute my asp.net-mvc views over multiple projects too :D

Comment: Can you do the same for single files? For example, if I want to have all but one file of my CSS folder to be replicated amongst several working repositories?

Answer (score 1):

Use svn [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals)